# Slide Up on click

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup

I have several `divs` on my Page. On Page load I want only the `First` div visible with a 'Show more' link. Then upon clicking the 'show more', I want to load `first three` divs and finally on clicking it for the second time I want it to `show all` divs.

So far its working fine. But after `show all`, when the span tag is clicked, it should slide up and hide all except the first div i.e it should reset the divs as they were originally on Page load so that it gives the `Show more/show less` effect.

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qo55rmuy/)** is the Fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="OffersContainer">
<div class='pan-box'>A</div>
<div class='pan-box'>B</div>
<div class='pan-box'>C</div>
<div class='pan-box'>D</div>
<div class='pan-box'>E</div>
<span>Show more</span>
</div>

<script>
$(".OffersContainer > div:gt(0)").hide();
var click = false;
var i = 1;
$(".OffersContainer > span").click(function() {
    if (i <= 2) {
        $(this).siblings(click ? "div:gt(0)" : "div:lt(3)").slideDown();
        click = true;
    } else {
        $(this).siblings("div:gt(0)").slideUp();
        click = false;
        i = 0;
    }

    i++;
});
</script>
```